# Remote server returned 500 Internal Server Error Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling here to be able to download a PDF file via WebAPI using .Net Framework 4.0

When call the rest server it is throwing a 500 error on the request.GetResponse(), and I am unable to see why. I have looked at various other examples, which I have followed, but I am still getting the same problem. Can anyone help?

Code below is what is in my RestFul Service:

```
          [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPdfRecordData()
    {

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(pdfDoc, FileMode.Open);
        stream.Position = 0;
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "pdf" };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "pdf";
        return result;
    }
```

The code below is where it is being called from the Winforms:

```
             private void GetPDF()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
        request.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        request.Method = "POST";

       HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

       byte[] bytes = null;
       using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
           int count = 0;
           do
           {
               byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
               count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
               ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
           } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);
           ms.Position = 0;
           bytes = ms.ToArray();
       }

       var filename = "pdf" + ".pdf";

       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
       HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

Full StackTrace:

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.GetPDF() in C:\Users\Andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 216
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.btnPDF_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 265
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: You need to post the full stacktrace...

Comment: Is your project WebApi only or do you also have access to MVC?

Comment: The Web API Project has been set up as MVC 4 templated Project. All the other Methods I have on the Project work when called from the WinForms Project. Therefore, Get, Get(id), Post, Delete - all work. This is a prototype project that I doing to de-risk from the main project

Comment: Also, your example is incomplete, what is `pdfDoc`? The rest of your `GetPdfRecordData()` method looks fine

Comment: Please note this is Web API Version 1 not 2!

Comment: A 500 on `GetResponse` leads me to believe you have an error on your web application. That stack trace is for the WinForms app, do you have one for the web app? Also, have you tried hitting the web app in the browser to at least check you're getting a happy response?

Comment: It is a string to the pdf document saved locall

Comment: I agree, it looks like a error from the WebApi, so the stack trace from the winforms doesn't help here.

Comment: There is only a rest service and a winform application. There are 4 other methods in the rest service get, get(id), post, and delete. All of these methods work and return results to winforms application. I am only getting an error on the pdf method

Comment: Does anyone have another solution to return a pdf via a rest service?